# Sharing the state across unrelated components - Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I am working on a svelte application, where I have created a store that I am updating on certain events. I have imported the store in another component with a different directory. I have subscribed to the store, so whenever any change is made on the store in one place, it should reflect the change in the subscribed component, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

**The Store**

```js
//Both with initial state as an empty array
export const current_embeds = writable([])
export const current_deletes = writable([])
```

**The script where I am updating the store**

```js
btn.onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  const linkdata = ctx.remove(vlink);
  if (linkdata) {
    //Updating the store
    current_deletes.update((prevState: Array < any > ): Array < any > => {
      return [...prevState, { ...linkdata
      }]
    })
  }
};
```

**Subscribed component**

```js
//Listens to changes 
current_embeds.subscribe(data => console.log('CURRENT EMBEDS NAV --- ', data));

current_deletes.subscribe(data => console.log('CURRENT DELETES NAV --- ', data));
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippets I’m not sure how do you handle subscribed component.
Here is a working REPL for your case:
https://svelte.dev/repl/44551e32530c46a19a3752b53a5e7732?version=3.24.1

What I noticed is that you must import and use your subsribed component (Comp.svelte) in main-app (or it’s subcomponent) in order to svelte recognize and run your  subscribed component. I don’t know how to ”activate” component in `<script>` part.

Comment: I have a file called edits.ts, there are two functions. First one get called when a user selects some text from the dom on `mousedown` and I update the state in this case. The second function is called when a user removes the selected text, I update the `delete_embeds`.

Comment: So its basically a script and not a component. But the store gets updated. There's a button in a component and I wont to enable it, when the store changes, so in that component I have subscribed to the store, in order to track the changes. But I am not getting any output in the component.

Comment: @NadeemAhmad it's quite impossible to help you with only a very limited view of your code. As grohjy has demonstrated, the concept works. Try and reproduce your problem in a codesandbox example, it'll make it easier to help you figure out what is wrong. Or perhaps you'll figure it out yourself while reproducing it ;)

Comment: Okay, gimme a minute

Comment: @ThomasHennes https://codesandbox.io/s/small-platform-o27k4

Here's the same case. it works here, but not with me

Comment: At a moment I’m not able to see your codesandbox. I updated my REPL so it doesn’t use svelte component any more, instead subscriptions are now in .js file. Subscription starts to work when you run it from main app, because then you have subscribed to updates (Duh, I feel stupid...)